# Don't repeat pronouns with relatives and personnal?

Tags: pronouns

I am doing an English homework, which consists in describing a process of actions.

I would like to say:
" The US are the worlrd leader in technology. The Japan only beats them in science, but there capacities are much more industrial-fit."

And I mean the US industrial capacities, and not the Japanese one. Is it understandable if I write it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as written this is not clear.

First of al, you should write "The United States **is**", not "the US **are**" ever since the US civil war, the country has been regarded as a single nation, not a collection of states, and the singular form is used. In formal or semi-formal writing such as a homework assignment, "US" should pe spelled out as "United States" at least the first time it is used.

Secondly, you should write "Japan" and not "**the** Japan". Unlike "the United States" or 'the Netherlands" but like the names of most other countries, "Japan" does not take an article.

Thirdly, "beats" is rather informal for this use, and is perhaps unduly combative. The word "surpasses" or "outdoes" would be better, in my view.

Fourthly, the word "there" is incorrect here, it should be "their", which is a possessive.

Fifthly, "industrial-fit" is an unusual and unclear term.

Finally the phrase

> ...but their capacities are much more industrial-fit."

does not make it clear **whose** capacities are better nor in what way exactly they are better. This phrase should be re-written, perhaps split off into one or more separate sentences.

Comment: +1, Kind of proofreading, but you had to do so. I can't see any other way to answer this question.

Comment: All country names are singular in (American) English. All plural country names take the article "The" to make them singular. The Philippines, The Maldives, etc.

Comment: @ ron, at least in historical usages, before 1870, one wrote "The Germanies are". Even now, I believe one writes "the United Arab Emirates are". Before 1860, The US government itself wrote "The United States are"

Comment: Thank you, I understand far better the point of English :)